# How to know the most followed accounts by the followers of a Twitter account?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I need to **calculate the most followed accounts by the followers of a given account**.

I found a first answer but I've a strong limitations : the **rate limit of [friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids) API is 15 calls per 15 minutes**. I can wait each time I hit the rate limit, but so, I need 10 hours to analyse a 600 followers Twitter account.

```rb
require "rubygems"
require "twitter"

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end

results = Hash.new(0)

Twitter.follower_ids(TWITTER_ACCOUNT_TO_ANALYSE).ids.each do |account|
  Twitter.friend_ids(account).ids.each do |id|
    results[id] +=1
  end
end   

puts results.sort_by {|key, value| value}.inspect
```

Do you a know a more interesting way or API to calculate that ? An approximative answer can be suffisant for my use.

**EDIT:**

Here is a version that manage rate limit and don't display solitaire followings :

```
require "rubygems"
require "twitter" 

Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY
    config.consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET
    config.oauth_token = OAUTH_TOKEN
    config.oauth_token_secret = OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end

results = Hash.new(0)

Twitter.follower_ids(TWITTER_ACCOUNT_TO_ANALYSE).ids.each do |account|
    begin
        Twitter.friend_ids(account).ids.each do |id|
            results[id] +=1
        end
    rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error #rate limit
        sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in
        retry
    rescue Twitter::Error::Unauthorized => error #protected account
        next        
    end
end

puts results.sort_by {|key, value| value}.keep_if {|key, value| value > 1}.inspect
```

Comment: I think this is more of a Twitter API question as opposed to Ruby Twitter API

Answer (score 1):

I work a good deal with the Twitter API (albeit with Python rather than Ruby), and as far as I know, you're out of luck here -- there's really no way around these rate limits for the API.

You are not the only one who's unhappy about this development. I, as well as numerous other developers, have commented on this very issue [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10644#comment-21949) -- given that the folks at Twitter have made no indication that these limits are going to change, it's probably safe to assume they're here to stay.

With the exception of paying a third party data provider who might have all this data scraped, you're basically stuck with the 15 calls per fifteen minutes.

On the other hand, if as you said, you're looking for an approximate answer, you might get away with taking a (statistically significant) sample of the followers of the original account. You didn't indicate how many followers there are for the original account, so I can't tell you the number of accounts you'd need to sample, but clearly there's no reason to pull in this data for all of the followers, assuming that the original account you're looking to analyze has a sufficiently large number of followers.

I suppose that, in a pinch, you might be able to use multiple IP addresses and Twitter accounts to speed up this job, but there's a decent amount of groundwork you'd have to lay to do that, and it runs against the spirit if not the letter if Twitter's terms of service.

I'm with you though -- 15 calls per 15 minutes for friends/followers data is no good.